# Problem with Spring Batch time between processor execution

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, chunks

I'm trying to execute a Spring Batch and i have a problem in the processor step.

I have 100.000 records to process more/less and i make my query and i sent to processor.

The problem comes here, i don't know why, spring batch take 80 seconds between chunk executions and i can't see where os the problem.

```
  @Bean
  public Job Mybatch(
      @Qualifier("stepOne") Step stepOne) {

    return jobBuilderFactory
        .get("Mybatch")
        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .start(stepOne)
        .next(xxx)
        .next(xxx)
        .next(xxx)
        .build();
  }



  @Bean
  public Step stepOne() throws Exception {
    return stepBuilderFactory
        .get("stepCreateCustomerProfile")
        .<Map<String, Object>, MyOutputObject>chunk(500)
        .reader(repositoryUserItemReader())
        .processor(myProcessor)
        .writer(writeMyObject())
        .faultTolerant()
        .skip(Exception.class)
        .skipLimit(250)
        .build();
  }
this is my processor
```

```
myService.accept(mapper.convertValue(userData, ProfileData.class));
//(This part call to a external api, this is not the problem)
final var myObject =
    new MyObject((Integer) user.get("user_id"), (String) userData.get("xxxxx"));
return myObject;
```

My writer is just a persist in the repository

```
  private ItemWriter<MyObject> writer() {
    RepositoryItemWriter<MyObject> itemWriter = new RepositoryItemWriter<>();
    itemWriter.setRepository(myRepository);
    itemWriter.setMethodName("save");
    return itemWriter;
  }
```

this is part of my code, and the image of the log
[image]

If anyone can help me... Thanks!!!

Comment: Without knowing what you are doing in your processor and writer this will be impossible to answer.

Comment: Don't add code as comments, edit your question.

Comment: Sorry M. Deinum, I updated the code with the lines of the processor... but is very simple processor.

Comment: You are calling an external service... 500 times. If each takes 500ms that adds up. So I think your processor is actually the problem here.

Comment: Also storing 500 entities at once with JPA can also be slow, so if you wrote your own writer instead of using a standard one this might be an issue as well.

Comment: But i Don't know the way to make in simple or with better performance that the save...
And the call to an api dont need the response... and is very fast.
The problem is the 80 seconds between the chunk, the execution is fast, but im trying to reduce the interval of chunks executions

Comment: Fast for a single call, but it will be called 500 in sequence before doing a save. So again if it takes 300 millis it takes 300 * 500 millis. So how fast is fast. Also saving 500 objects at once is also (kind of) slow as each save leads to a dirty check which exponentially grows with more objects. So both add up, decrease your chunksize, for starters and measure the different parts to where the time is being spend. My money is still on the processor. The chunk is the whole procss of read, process, write so 1 chunk takes 80 seconds.

Comment: The fact that you don't need the response doesn't mean the implementation is fire-and-forget (we don't know the implementation). There is also conversion (twice) going on in your mapper and I would strongly suggest to use the `JpaItemWriter` instead of the `RepositoryItemWriter` as the latter uses reflection which adds additional overhead.